# Error While Sending Email through Outlook from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have write a macro in outlook and excel vba, the description are:
1. Code in Outlook for Open Excel file if email subject line match :

```
Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        '// Subject line here
        If InStr(Item.Subject, "Run Dashboard") Then
            Call openExcel
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Once Excel is open and dashboard has run then email has to be sent via excel.

vba and code:

```
Dim outapp As Object
Dim nmail As Object

Set outapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set nmail = outapp.CreateItem(0)
With nmail
    .To = "xxxxxx@xxxx.com"
    .cc = ""
    .bcc = ""
    .Subject = flname
    .htmlbody = RangetoHTML(Range("A1:" & Split(Cells(, lastcol1).Address, "$")(1) & lastrow1))
    .attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    .display
End With

On Error GoTo 0

Set nmail = Nothing

Set outapp = Nothing
```

Now I am facing the error on `Set outapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` 
This error is only showing if i open excel file through outlook email as mentioned in point 1, if i open file in normal way i.e. without outlook help, then code is running successfully.

Please help in the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: instead of `Dim outapp as object` Have you tried with `Dim outapp as outlook.Application` and `Dim nmail as outlook.MailItem` Also check whether the `Microsoft Outlook` reference is included

Comment: Thanks this worked :)

Comment: now getting error on "Set nmail = outapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)" in excel vba

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to automate Excel from Outlook and then Outlook from Excel?

```
 Set outapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Instead you may get the running Outlook instance (if any) because only one instance of Outlook can be run simultaneously. See [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/201096) and [GetObject and CreateObject behavior of Office automation servers](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/288902) for more information.

Try to use the following line of code instead:

```
 Set nmail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
```

If you have multiple profiles in Outlook configured most probably you will need to use the [Logon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861594.aspx) method of the Namespace class.

Comment: I think "Set nmail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)" only can be use while i am using this code in outlook not in excel, i am getting error in excel vba